# Are there any rabbinic opinions on gambling for fantasy football?

Tags: gambling

I do not particularly know the halachot of gambling, however, I have heard that under certain circumstances playing fantasy football might be allowed, if you do not expect to win money. I do not know if this is a real opinion or just something I may remember incorrectly. Has anyone else heard this or heard something similar?

Comment: You mean aside from the giant-waste-of-time aspect of it?

Comment: Everyone has things they enjoy, yes.

Comment: Indeed and they should pick the productive ones to engage in. It's just hard to imagine any posek taking the gambling question part of this question seriously given the glaring other issues at play.

Comment: Well why would a posek ever answer any gambling question then, given that its a waste of time?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.koltorah.org/halachah/farewell-to-fantasy-football-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter%3fformat=amp